# What to put for primary occupation in the DS-160 form when uni date has been pushed back?

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, f1-visas, student-visas

I was supposed to attend university starting fall 2020 but due to the pandemic my final semester exams were postponed and I had to defer my admission to spring 2021.

So, I graduated in September and I'm not working anywhere. I have my F1 visa interview in a week. Should I select 'not employed' and specify the reason that I recently graduated and am awaiting university to start? Or should I select the student option and fill in the details of the university I'm intending to attend in spring?

Comment: You’re still a student on a *gap year*. Of course you can also say unemployed and be ready for the consequences. 

Comment: What happened with your visa interview? I have the same situation as you. I deferred my university admission from fall 20' to fall 21'. I have my visa interview next month. What should I fill in DS 160??